# evaluating this limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a}{ak+n}$

Tags: limits

I try to get the limit of the following expression (should be valid for $a\geq 0$):

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a}{ak+n}$

Unfortunately nothing worked. I tried to rewrite the expressiona and to use l'hospitals rule, but it didn't work.

Thank you for any help:)

regards

Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the given sum on the Riemann sum's form:

$$\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{a}{a\frac kn+1}\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\int_0^1\frac{a}{ax+1}dx=\ln(ax+1)\Bigg|_0^1=\ln(a+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Besides the simple 'Riemann Sum Method':
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\lim_{n\ \to\infty}\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{n}{a \over ak + n}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\infty}\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
\pars{{1 \over k + n/a} - {1 \over k + n + 1+ n/a}}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\infty}\bracks{\pars{n + 1}\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}
{1 \over \pars{k + n + 1 + n/a}\pars{k + n/a}}}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\infty}\bracks{\pars{n + 1}\,
{\Psi\pars{n + 1 + n/a} - \Psi\pars{n/a} \over \pars{n + 1 + n/a} - n/a}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\infty}\bracks{\Psi\pars{n + 1 + {n \over a}} - \Psi\pars{n \over a}}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\infty}\bracks{%
\ln\pars{n + 1 + {n \over a}} - \ln\pars{n \over a}}
=\lim_{n\ \to\infty}\ln\pars{n\bracks{a + 1} + a \over n}
=\color{#66f}{\large\ln\pars{a + 1}}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\Psi\pars{z}}$ is the Digamma Function which satisfies
>   $$
> \Psi\pars{z} \sim \ln\pars{z}\,,\qquad\verts{z} \ggg 1\,,\quad\verts{{\rm arg}\pars{z}} < \pi
> $$

Comment: I really like this solution, it looks great. Unfortunately it contains many steps which are not easy to understand for me. For example i don't understand the first step (how was this transformation done?), and also the next steps are a bit magic for me. And it's the first time i see the digamma function:) But i'll study this solution again:)